# autocorrelation peak

Tags: digital-communications

Let $s(t)$ a signal of duration $T_s$ on a bandwidth $B$. The matched filtering of this signal gives: $R=max|s(t) \ast s^{\ast}(-t)|$ and here theoretically I saw that $R=BT_s$.

But does anyone know of rigorous proof of this result?

Comment: There are two incorrect claims here. One is that that the matched filter output is a scalar (it is actually another signal). The second is that the value you give for $R$ is wrong; for example, the matched filter's output depends on the energy of $s(t)$.

Comment: I think you are mixing up two different concepts that unfortunately use the same letter of the alphabet. The latter $R$ seems to be a _rate_; the former an autocorrelation value.

Answer (score 0):

The autocorrelation itslef is a continuous signal which is sampled at the symbol rate to get the peak /Max.

Then you are talking about the symbol/bit rate which ofcourse in a noiseless scenario will be close to the channel capacity